# How can I get information on my template failing to start?

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs, azure-lab-services

I'm using Azure Labs Services (for classrooms), and I can't start my Template VM. The "start VM" trigger will work, but the VM will fail to start and return to a "stopped" state without any error message in the Labs environment or the Azure Portal. Is there a way I can pull more debugging information as to why my Template didn't start, or a possible troubleshooting option from someone who's experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can troubleshoot it further by checking the Activity logs of your Lab account from within the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) as follows:

[image: Azure Lab Account Activity Logs]

Expanding the failed event further, you should be able to see the **Error code** and the **Message**. Switching to the JSON representation, look for the `statusMessage` key within `properties` that has more details.

For example:

```
..
"properties": {
    "statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",\"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",\"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\"details\":[{\"code\":\"ResourceGroupNotFound\",\"message\":\"Resource group 'MX-RG-xxxxx' could not be found.\"}]}}"
},
..
```

This should hopefully give you enough information to take the next steps.

There's an ongoing outage for Azure Lab Services. Please follow updates [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-lab-services/update-lab-services-outage-cannot-perform-actions-on-a-lab/m-p/1253540?followUserID=508307).